# filter twig passing variables

Tags: symfony, twig

I am doing a twig filter and want to do something like this:

```
{{'<p> hello {{name}} </p>' | try ("loksea") }}
```

but not have access to var name. first access to name and then second parse filter. its my filter method:

```
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
         'try'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'tryFilter',array('is_safe' => array('html')))
    );
}

public function tryFilter($value,$otro)
{
    return '<h1 ' . 'id="' .$otro.'">'.$value .'</h1>';
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'demo';
}
```

thanks.

Comment: this is not really clear...what are you trying to do? What is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that I can not access the variable name. if name is ryan.

step filter: '<p> hello ryan </ p>'

but the problem is that I can not access name on that site. sorry for my english

Comment: i tried {% set var1 = 'test' %}

{{'<p>'var1'</p>'|try("loksea") }} but not working.:(

Comment: the solution is {% set var2 %}
    <div id="pagination">
        {{name}}
    </div>
{% endset %} thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try concatenate string. In twig concatenation operator is `~`. So try this one:

```
{{'<p> hello ' ~ name ~ ' </p>' | try ("loksea") }}
```

Twig docs: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators

Comment: Couldn't you just put the tags outside? <p> hello {{ name | try("loksea") }} </p>